# Adding a pivot to a rollup

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

I have the following query that gives me aggregated data that I would like to pivot:

```
select provider, title, hd_or_sd, SUM(customer_price), count(distinct title) 
from `100` group by provider, title, hd_or_sd with rollup
```

[image]

I would like to pivot on the `sd_or_hd` column, so that my result looks like:

```
                                      hd              sd          total   
provider         title             rev. count      rev. count   rev. count
DISTRIBBER                                         16.99  1     16.99  1
DISTRIBBER       finding Joe                       16.99  1     16.99  1
```

How would I do this query? Also, I have noticed that the Rollup is not perfect -- for example, with Electric entertainment, it shows 5 titles but has the hd_or_sd value "HD", even though several of those titles are SD. Why does this occur?

Here is a sample of the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9b5d9/1. And here is what the final result should be (minus the strange number formatting) -- 
[image]

Note that I'd also like to accomplish this without using `CASE` statements as the pivoted column could potentially have many different values.

Comment: So, you decided to go with rollup then? In order to rollup by `hd_or_sd` you need to group by `hd_or_sd`

Comment: @cha oh I see -- thank you.

Comment: It would help if you put the values in your expected result

Comment: @cha please see updated question with expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SUM with CASE Operator, like this:

```
select provider, title, 
sum(case when hd_or_sd = 'HD' then 1 else 0 end) as HD,
sum(case when hd_or_sd = 'SD' then 1 else 0 end) as SD,
sum(case when hd_or_sd = 'HD' then customer_price else 0 end) as HD_price,
sum(case when hd_or_sd = 'SD' then customer_price else 0 end) as SD_price,
sum(customer_price) revenue from `100`
group by provider, title
with rollup
```

Result:

```
|               provider |                      title | HD | SD | HD_price | SD_price | revenue |
|------------------------|----------------------------|----|----|----------|----------|---------|
|             DISTRIBBER |                Finding Joe |  0 |  1 |        0 |    16.99 |   16.99 |
|             DISTRIBBER |                     (null) |  0 |  1 |        0 |    16.99 |   16.99 |
|            Echo Bridge |               Do Something |  0 |  1 |        0 |     1.99 |    1.99 |
|            Echo Bridge |                 Down in LA |  2 |  2 |        0 |        0 |       0 |
|            Echo Bridge | The L.A. Complex, Season 1 |  0 |  1 |        0 |    19.99 |   19.99 |
|            Echo Bridge | The Other Side of the Door |  1 |  2 |     2.99 |     3.98 |    6.97 |
|            Echo Bridge |               Who You Know |  0 |  2 |        0 |     3.98 |    3.98 |
|            Echo Bridge |                     (null) |  3 |  8 |     2.99 |    29.94 |   32.93 |
| Electric Entertainment |         Leverage, Season 4 |  0 |  1 |        0 |    31.99 |   31.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |     The Cross My Heart Job |  1 |  0 |     2.99 |        0 |    2.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |             The Inside Job |  0 |  1 |        0 |     1.99 |    1.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |              The Radio Job |  0 |  1 |        0 |     1.99 |    1.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |       The Scheherazade Job |  1 |  0 |     2.99 |        0 |    2.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |                     (null) |  2 |  3 |     5.98 |    35.97 |   41.95 |
|               HALLMARK |      The Good Witch's Gift |  0 |  1 |        0 |     3.99 |    3.99 |
|               HALLMARK |                     (null) |  0 |  1 |        0 |     3.99 |    3.99 |
|            Quebec Inc. |        2 Frogs In the West |  1 |  0 |     5.99 |        0 |    5.99 |
|            Quebec Inc. |                     (null) |  1 |  0 |     5.99 |        0 |    5.99 |
|                 VIRGIL |         One Lucky Elephant |  0 |  1 |        0 |     3.99 |    3.99 |
|                 VIRGIL |                     (null) |  0 |  1 |        0 |     3.99 |    3.99 |
|                 (null) |                     (null) |  6 | 14 |    14.96 |    90.88 |  105.84 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2baff/3)

Alternatively, you can just simply ROLLUP by hd_or_sd and have the PIVOT done in the application, like this:

```
select provider, title, hd_or_sd,
sum(customer_price) revenue from `100`
group by provider, hd_or_sd, title
with rollup
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the case operator here, as in the pivot there may be many values. It works in this case, but doesn't work in most of the other cases we have. Is it possible to change this to work without a bunch of `CASE`s? Anyways, this works, so I've +1'd it.

Comment: you can get away with the ROLLUP if you change the group by to this: `group by provider, hd_or_sd, title`